# Error when converting to current syntax

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

Last year, I did a tutorial on how to create a camera app. Today I tried to run it but it needed to be converted to the current syntax. After fixing a majority of the errors, I'm now left with just one error that I can't fix. I'm not too familiar with AVFoundation or Swift 4 yet so I was hoping that I could receive some sort of assistance. The error that Im getting is on line 61/62:

[image: "Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not [AVCaptureDevice]"]

> Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not [AVCaptureDevice]

Here's the relevant code:

```
//capture devices
func configureCaptureDevices() throws {
    let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [], mediaType: <#T##AVMediaType?#>, position: <#T##AVCaptureDevice.Position#>)
    guard let cameras = (session.devices.flatMap { $0 }), !cameras.isEmpty else { throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable}

    for camera in cameras {
        if camera.position == .front {
            self.frontCamera = camera
        }

        if camera.position == .back {
            self.rearCamera = camera

            try camera.lockForConfiguration()
            camera.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
            camera.unlockForConfiguration()
        }

    }
}
```

And finally, a link to the tutorial I was following: https://www.appcoda.com/avfoundation-swift-guide/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `guard let` syntax which is only for binding optionals. And you've correctly deduced that `session` is no longer optional (which is why you removed the `?`). So pull the assignment of `cameras` out of the `guard` statement:

```
let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)
let cameras = session.devices.flatMap { $0 }
guard !cameras.isEmpty else { throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable }
```

Personally, now that we're no longer doing any optional binding, I'd replace that `guard` statement with a more intuitive `if` statement. I also don't believe that `flatMap` is needed (you use that when dealing with arrays of arrays or arrays of optionals, neither of which applies here):

```
let cameras = session.devices
if cameras.isEmpty { throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable }
```